# Quebrando tabela em várias páginas

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Estou criando uma aplicação Web que exibi duas tabelas de tamanhos iguais
Porém, ambas possuem cerca de 100 linhas cada, gostaria que fossem exibido apenas 25 linhas de cada tabela e para ver o resto da tabela teria aquelas páginas subsequentes: 1, 2, 3 ,4...

Tudo que eu fiz até agr foi apenas com php, mysql, css e html.
iria precisar de javascript, Jquery ou outros?

Obrigado

Comment: Pesquise sobre Bootstrap Table, é exatamente oque você quer, mas está tudo meio que pronto. Você só precisa ter conhecimento em Jquery (biblioteca Java Script).

Comment: Eu uso o [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) pra fazer isso, mas tem que conhecer JQuery.

Comment: Esse DataTables parece ser bem fácil, vou tentar por ele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível dividir a tabela em diferentes páginas usando somente php/mysql.

Para recuperar somente parte dos resultados do MySQL, use o `LIMIT` na sua query. Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo='valor' LIMIT 0,25
```

A consulta acima irá recuperar as primeiras 25 linhas da consulta. Para recuperar as próximas 25 entradas, utilize `LIMIT 25,25` (o primeiro parâmetro é o offset, ou seja, quantas linhas deseja "pular" ao recuperar os resultados, e o segundo parâmetro é quantas linhas trazer).

Já para pular de uma página pra outra, a sugestão é usar uma variável GET (variáveis que ficam na URL da página). Assim, se a sua página está no endereço **www.exemplo.com.br/tabela.php**, é só criar um link para a próxima página usando **www.exemplo.com.br/tabela.php?pagina=2**, por exemplo. Para pegar o valor da variável no PHP é só usar `$_GET['pagina']`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Realmente assim é um jeito bem interessante de fazer, porém, diariamente essa tabela vai ser alimentada com dados novos, dessa forma, as páginas não são automaticas são?
Pelo oq eu entendi eu teria que criar diversas querys pra cada página.

Comment: Não, não teria. A query seria a mesma sempre, vc só iria passar o offset como um parâmetro para a query.

Comment: Consegui fazer pela forma que vc falou, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

existe um plugin que se chama data-tables, que na minha opinião é o melhor ele te da varias opções para tabelas, pesquisa de dados da tabela etc ex: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

creio que você consiga usar adicionando essas tags aqui no seu código mas para melhor entendimento sugiro ver a documentação https://datatables.net/

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```